# How to strip hours from date & hour string in Python

Tags: python

My script receives argument as : `'2018-07-11 15:00'`
I want to remove the hours from it so only `'2018-07-11'` is left.

When I do:

```
import datetime
if __name__ == '__main__':
  requestedDate = sys.argv[1]
  requestedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(requestedDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

It gives me this error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  15:00:00
```

Is there a simply way to remove the hour from the string?

I need it as a string. no need for `datetime` object. This is simply going to be a file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split it at the first space, and keep the first part

```
 requestedDate = sys.argv[1]
 requestedDate = requestedDate.split()[0]
```

Comment: if you use only the first part of what split returns, you could set a maxsplit like `(...).split(' ', 1)[0]`

Comment: @Aemyl why is that different than blue_note answer?

Comment: @jack it's faster because `split` doesn't have to process the whole string. However, this is probably only measurable for very long strings. There is also `str.partition` which is also faster than a pure `split()`

Answer (score 1):

If you receive strings like `'2018-07-11 15:00'` you could just split them to retrieve what you need.

```
requestedDate = sys.argv[1].split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
if __name__ == '__main__':
  requestedDate = sys.argv[1].split(" ")[0]
  requestedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(requestedDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip the time:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(requestedDate[:10], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    requestedDate = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```